# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'geometry'

Tags: python, attributeerror, geopandas

when trying to collect a lot of points using append,

```
pointlist = Polygon(point_list)
M_point.append(pointlist)
shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=M_point.geometry)
```

it shows an error, 'list' object has no attribute 'geometry'

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=M_point.geometry)
```

how can I solve that? any ideas?

Comment: why your variable `M_point` should have the attribute `geometry`?

Comment: If `pointlist` is a list of points, then you want to use `extend` rather than `append`,

Comment: I forgot to write  ... point_list = [(xlon[0],ylat[1]),(xlon[1],ylat[1]),(xlon[1],ylat[0]),(xlon[0],ylat[0])] 
pointlist = Polygon(point_list) ... it's a dataframe

Comment: Did you mean `shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=M_point).geometry`? I think you want the geometry column _after_ the dataframe has been created.

Comment: I tried to change it to extend, but now I get this error

AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'extend'

I want to save a layer of other points of polygons (in total 4 layers), how can it be saved in a variable and then saved as shapefile or netcdf (all layers)?